# How to attach an existing sqlite database to the .apk project?

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi

What I want is attach the database it inside the .apk. I would not like to copy it physically to the mobile device either. What I am doing now is create the database with sql scripts...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Put it in the assets folder.  Then at runtime, copy it from the assets directory to the filesystem if you haven't already.

Comment: when i compile for android and delphi create the folders, i copy the database for the assets folder?, i use delphi and firemonkey.....thanks!!!

Comment: No, use: Project|Deployment from the IDE menu and add the database to the deployment, as per https://community.embarcadero.com/article/articles-tutorials/151-ui/927-deploying-and-accessing-local-files-on-ios-and-android

Answer (score 0):

Go to project -> Deployment -> add file -> locate and add your Database 
after that select your database in the deployment page and click on the button "remote path" or just double click in the tab

[image]

set the remote path as shown in the picture to " assets\internal\ "

**NOTE :**

*Internal = Internal device memory*

*External =  SDCard*

Save
after that on your Main Application form in the Even OnCreat assign the Database path with this code :

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'DatabaseName')
```

**NOTE :**

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'filename')  { Internal }
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'filename')  { External }
```

[Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files)